# Why am I missing using directive or assembly reference ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET project. The namespace is `MyNameSpace`. Among the cs files in this project is TestClass.cs:

```
namespace MyNameSpace 
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There is another class, Products. In the Product.cs class:

```
namespace MyNameSpace 
{

    public class Product
    {
        public string ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


        public TestClass testClass; <==Doesn't work.
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it work? I've cleaned the solution, rebuilt, etc. There's no Intellisense for TestClass. I'm sure this is something stupid I'm doing but what?

Comment: @Kith: There is something wrong. It *still* has a period after the class name. Although the question is poorly written and apparently included errors, which makes it hard to know what the OP's code really looks like.

Comment: @JonathanWood That's my point. In a comment to the only answer in this question, he claims that the period is just a typo. We can't help him if we don't know what the code really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the `TestClass.cs` file in your Solution Explorer. Make sure the Build Action is set to **Compile**. You should then get Intellisense on that class and your `Product` class should be able to see `TestClass`.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, please don't post questions that ask why "it doesn't work." That's not how programmers think. What happens exactly?

Second, there is no period after the namespace name.

*Note: It's hard to tell if the periods are really in the code because this Aravol character has been editing the crap out of the question and it appears he removed one of the periods.*